# How can I numerically solve a least square problem with L2 penalty

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, image-processing

I want to solve a least square problem that:
\begin{equation*}
\text{minimize } \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}\lambda\|x\|_2^2  
\end{equation*}

From the normal equation, I have to solve the normal equation that:
\begin{equation*}  (A^TA + \lambda I)x = A^Tb\end{equation*}

But in my problem, $A$ is a very high dimensional matrix ($A \in R^{512^2 \times 512^2}$), so I can not use method like QR decomposition. How can I solve this problem?

If helps, $A$ is a convolution operator in image processing, but it can be represented in a matrix form.

Comment: Can method like fft help to solve this problem?

Comment: Use an iterative method, like conjugate gradient. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method

Comment: If your problem is as large as you claim, then you need a method which only does mat-vec operattions. As sugested by the previous commenter, CG is reasonable choice.